# Pandas does not append rows within a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following loop:

```
lines = []

for dicom in mydicoms:

    dcm1 = pydicom.dcmread(dicom)


    identity = dcm1.PatientID
    age = dcm1.PatientAge
    sex = dcm1.PatientSex
    modality = dcm1.Modality
    finding = dcm1.StudyDescription
    rows = dcm1.Rows
    columns = dcm1.Columns



    new_row = {'id':identity, 'age':age, 'sex':sex, 'modality':modality, 'finding':finding, 'rows':rows, 'columns':columns}
    df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)


    lines.append(new_row)
```

When I check df afterwards it is empty.

When I copy and paste parts of the code from the loop or do any of the following in another Jupyter cell:

```
df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

df.append(lines, ignore_index = True)
```

it appends it correctly, just not inside the loop.

What am I missing?

Comment: you have to assign it back inside the loop `df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)`

Comment: Anyway you do not want to do that. Appending to a dataframe row by row in a loop is terribly inefficient. Just append the rows to a list and then append the full list to the dataframe in one single pass.

Comment: True. It works. Such a small omission, I would not have spotted it on my own, ESPECIALLY given the fact that  same lines work WITHOUT df = ****** on their own.

Why is it that it works in another cell, but not inside of a loop? 

Now I am even more confused.

Comment: Thanks Serge. That is what df.append(lines, ignore_index = True) does. It is essentially a list of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned by [anky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky), you should assign it back to the `df` variable.

Here's your code with the correction:

```
lines = []

for dicom in mydicoms:

    dcm1 = pydicom.dcmread(dicom)


    identity = dcm1.PatientID
    age = dcm1.PatientAge
    sex = dcm1.PatientSex
    modality = dcm1.Modality
    finding = dcm1.StudyDescription
    rows = dcm1.Rows
    columns = dcm1.Columns



    new_row = {'id':identity, 'age':age, 'sex':sex, 'modality':modality, 'finding':finding, 'rows':rows, 'columns':columns}
    df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index = True)


    lines.append(new_row)
```

Comment: True. It works. Such a small omission, I would not have spotted it on my own, ESPECIALLY given the fact that  same lines work WITHOUT df = ******* on their own.

Why is it that it works in another cell, but not inside of a loop? 

Now I am even more confused.

Comment: The problem here is not the loop. you are probably testing in the terminal and seeing the new object returned by ``df.append``. Try running it on the terminal and then calling the object again, it should be the original ``df`` variable.